# Parse nested (opaque, any-typed) Protobuf message

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a message envelope:

```
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message Envelope {
    string type = 1;
    int32 version = 2;
    string message_id = 5;
    string timestamp = 6;
    google.protobuf.Any message = 7;
}
```

Now, I happen to know that the message is another Protobuf value with the following type:
And a message defined as follows:

```
message Message {
    int32 value = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Is it possible for me to do a one-shot parsing of this combined message? I am thinking that the problem with substituting `Any` with `Message` is the field numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` is just:

```cs
message Any {
  string type_url = 1;
  bytes value = 2;
}
```

where the `value` is just the regular payload content. If you *know* that the type is your `Message`, then you can use instead

```cs
message Envelope {
    string type = 1;
    int32 version = 2;
    string message_id = 5;
    string timestamp = 6;
    FakeAny message = 7;
}
message FakeAny {
  // don't even need to capture the type_url
  Message value = 2;
}
message Message {
    int32 value = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

and it *should* deserialize directly.